# Changing the icon of an executable in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

I am programming in C++ using Visual Studio 2022 and I'd like to change the icon of my executable (.exe).
So far I've only found out how to do that for Visual Studio 2019 or C#.
Is there a way to do it for Visual Studio 2022 and C++?

I followed several tutorials for other versions of Visual Studio or other programming languages, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since my last native windows program, so this might be outdated. Hopefully it's going to point you in the right direction:

- First you need to add the .ico file as a resource to your project. I think you can do this by going to Add -> Resource and select Icon.
- Once you have you icon embedded as a resource, you need to open the .rc file that was created in the previous step and add

  MAINICON ICON "foo.ico"

Where foo.ico is your icon file name.

When you build, you should get that icon as your executable icon.